# Checking for a string against a list of strings

Tags: ios, string, nsarray

I am trying to check a string against a whole list of strings. I have an MKMapView and when I get a bunch of results, I would like to exclude all results that contain a list of strings, for example "Object", "Test", "Example". So if a location is called "Object Factory", it would not show on the map. If a different string was called "Test Area", it also would not show on the map. The weird thing with the code bellow is that if I switch it so it only shows the strings containing "Object", "Test", "Example" they are the only ones that show, but if I switch it so that all strings except these show, it doesn't work and all of the strings including the unwanted ones show.

```
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                       @"Object",
                                       @"Test",
                                       @"Example",
                                       nil];

            for (NSString *s in arrayOfStrings)
            {
                if ([item.name rangeOfString:s options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound) {

                    NSLog(@"Here it is: %@", s);
                    NSLog(@"Good String");
                    [self.pastURLs addObject:item.name];
                    NSLog(@"Here is pastURLS count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.pastURLs.count);
                    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

                }
            }
```

Here is when it works, but the wrong way:

```
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                       @"Object",
                                       @"Test",
                                       @"Example",
                                       nil];

            for (NSString *s in arrayOfStrings)
            {
                if ([item.name rangeOfString:s options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {

                    NSLog(@"Here it is: %@", s);
                    NSLog(@"Good String");
                    [self.pastURLs addObject:item.name];
                    NSLog(@"Here is pastURLS count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.pastURLs.count);
                    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic adds a string to your pastURLs array if ANY one of your target strings is not found in it. You want to add it if NONE of the target strings is found. Try this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                       @"Object",
                                       @"Test",
                                       @"Example",
                                       nil];

        BOOL stringFound = NO;

        for (NSString *s in arrayOfStrings)
        {
            if ([item.name rangeOfString:s options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {

                // we found something, don't include
                stringFound = YES;
            }
        }
        if(!stringFound) {
            NSLog(@"Good String");
            [self.pastURLs addObject:item.name];
            NSLog(@"Here is pastURLS count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.pastURLs.count);
            [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        }
```